# How to create library of a self-written static function in python

Tags: python, function, python-imaging-library

I have a python script which has multiple static functions. I want to convert that complete python script into a python library

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import EA_Upload_config as cfg
import datetime

#%%
def clockPrint(sentence):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    date_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print(date_time + " : " + sentence)


def uploadToEA(df_,ds_api_name,operation_,instance,xmd_=None): #Upsert #Overwrite
    import SalesforceEinsteinAnalytics as EA
    clockPrint("Upload Process Initiated for "+instance+" instance...")
    if instance.lower() == 'commercial':
        EAS = EA.salesforceEinsteinAnalytics(env_url='https://spglobalratings.my.salesforce.com', browser='chrome')
    if instance.lower() == 'analytical':
        EAS = EA.salesforceEinsteinAnalytics(env_url='https://spglobalratingsae.my.salesforce.com', browser='chrome')

    EAS.load_df_to_EA(df_,dataset_api_name=ds_api_name, operation=operation_,xmd=xmd_,fillna=False) #Error because of fillna=False
    clockPrint("Upload Process Completed successfully for "+instance+" instance. Navigate to (Einstein Analytics --> Data Manager --> Monitor) to check progress.")


def processDate(date):
    if pd.isnull(date):
        return np.nan
    else:
        date = pd.to_datetime(date)
        date = datetime.datetime.strftime(date,"%m/%d/%Y")
        return date


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv(cfg.FILE_PATH)
    if len(cfg.DATE_COLUMNS) != 0:
        for c in cfg.DATE_COLUMNS:
            df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda x: processDate(x))

    for c in df.columns:
        if df[c].dtype == "O":
            df[c].fillna('', inplace=True)
        elif np.issubdtype(df[c].dtype, np.number):
            df[c].fillna(0, inplace=True)
        elif df[c].dtype == "datetime64[ns]":
            df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda x: processDate(x))
            df[c].fillna("", inplace=True)

    df.fillna("", inplace=True)
    for instance in cfg.INSTANCES:
        if instance.lower() == 'commercial':
            uploadToEA(df, cfg.COM_DATASET_API_NAME, cfg.COM_OPERATION, instance, cfg.COM_XMD)
        elif instance.lower() == 'analytical':
            uploadToEA(df, cfg.ANA_DATASET_API_NAME, cfg.ANA_OPERATION, instance, cfg.ANA_XMD)
        else: clockPrint("Update INSTANCES variable as ['Commercial'] or ['Analytical'] or ['Commercial','Analytical'].")
```

This is my complete python script which I want to convert it into a library. How should I do it?

Comment: What is your goal? To use the script like a builtin python module on your own machine? To publish it on pypi or github?

Comment: So, what is the difference between a Python module (which it is now) and a library?

Comment: @timgeb My goal is to use convert this python script into a library (So next time instead of opening this entire code, I just should get everything in a single line). Like we have a library named numpy, we just write import numpy and can access any function from it like numpy.sum etc. In short, I want to use this script like a builtin python package(library) in my machine.

Comment: @KlausD. Library is a collection of modules (consider these functions as a module) and want to convert everything (all the functions(modules) in it into a library)

Comment: You can just put the file into any directory where Python looks for modules. Print out `sys.path`.